# Using composite API is it possible to pass all Id's from a GET operation to another GET operation without knowing how many objects are being returned?

Tags: soql, api, composite

With composite we can use the results from a previous operation in the next operation by using the @{ref.records[0].} syntax as so:

```
{
  "compositeRequest": [
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/services/data/v46.0/query?q=select+Id+,name+from+account+limit+2",
    "referenceId": "ref1"
  },
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/Account/@{ref1.records[0].Id}",
    "referenceId": "ref2"
  }
}
```

My question, is there some sort of syntax that can enumerate the results from ref1 and pass all the Id's to a subquery in ref2? Something like so:

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "url": "/services/data/v46.0/query?q=select+Id+,name+from+account+where+Id+in+(@{ref1.records.ITERATE_ALL_IDs})",
  "referenceId": "ref2"
}
```

The reason being that ref1 could return a variable amount of records so explicitly referencing each item in the array is not feasible.

This could be accomplished using two API calls where the first one retrieves the Id's and the second one uses those Id's but I would prefer to do this in the same composite API call.